# Regular expression matching length and letters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match up to a couple criteria.

the string needs to be 8 characters long, and can only have the following letters in it: `urdl`.

I think it'd be something similar to `/(.{8}('u')('r')('d')('l'))/`

Can you help me out?

Comment: I really am completely lost when it comes to regular expressions.  For the most part, I think I'd start with something similar to this: `/(.{8}('u')('r')('d')('l'))/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can use "^[urdl]{8}$", which ensures that the length is exactly 8 characters (and no more and no less). The "^" means the beginning, "$" represents the end, and there are 8 characters - "{8}" which each match one of the letters in the set "[urdl]".

Answer (score 2):

Regex has some different flavors but in python you could use: `'[ulrd]{8}'` as your expression.